# Angular: one-time binding, recompiling of nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using one-time binding and [kcd-recompile](http://kentcdodds.com/kcd-angular/#/kcd-recompile), but have a problem with nested `ng-repeat`. Let's assume the code looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in ::people">
    <div ng-repeat="friend in ::person.friends" kcd-recompile="person.friends">
        {{friend.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

If I add a friend to one of the people now, I want this person div to be recompiled without recompiling the other people's divs. The problem is: `person.friends` is only updated, if `person` is updated.

So it works if I add the `kcd-recompile` to the first `ng-repeat`, but then every person's div is recompiled (which I want to prevent).

Is there any possibility to update `person` without recompiling the whole first `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on my own (after hours), if anyone needs it:

Using `people[$index].friends` instead of `person.friends`, it works!

`<div ng-repeat="person in ::people">
    <div ng-repeat="friend in people[$index].friends" kcd-recompile="person.friends">
        {{friend.name}}
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: note in your post you have `::person` but here just `people[$index].friends`, so possibly `<div ng-repeat="friend in person.friends"` also works

Comment: but with `::people[$index].friends` anyway work? or also does not?